# Why are my SDL/C++ images disappearing?

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I'm making a little game engine as a side project but for some reason I'm getting a really weird problem.

It's to do with the sprites. I'm loading the sprites fine, I seem to render fine. But when the x, y of the sprites are close to each other, one of the tiles  either vanish or go in the wrong position. Usually it's off by 32 whether it's x or y.

```
void SpriteLoader::loadSprites(SDL_Renderer* renderer)
{
    loadSprite("assets/grass.png", "grass", renderer);
    loadSprite("assets/grass_full.png", "grass2", renderer);
}

void SpriteLoader::renderSprites(SDL_Renderer* renderer)
{
    drawSprite("grass", 0, 0, 32, 32, renderer);
    drawSprite("grass2", 64, 32, 32, 32, renderer);

}
```

Here is the image:

[image]

```cpp
void SpriteLoader::drawSprite(std::string id, int x, int y, int width, int height, SDL_Renderer* renderer, SDL_RendererFlip flip)
{
    SDL_Rect srcRect;
    SDL_Rect destRect;

    srcRect.x = 0;
    srcRect.y = 0;
    srcRect.w = destRect.w = width;
    srcRect.h = destRect.h = height;
    destRect.x = y;
    destRect.y = y;

    SDL_RenderCopyEx(renderer, textures[id], &srcRect, &destRect, 0, 0, flip);
}
```

Comment: Those are the exact (x,y) for the picture.

Comment: What units are the X and Y in?  Do you have the correct scale and offset?  (ie Should you consider -ve and +ve values for X and Y)

Comment: From what i'm aware, SDL's image origin is always set at 0,0. So an offset doesn't seem to be necessary .

Comment: Can you post an image of what it does when you put in the 'proper' X and Y, which I assume is 32,32?   (Maybe the units of your canvas are not aligned with the units you are using?)

Comment: If the x and y are at 32, 32 you will get the image above as well.

Comment: Can you show the `drawSprite` code please?

Comment: This is pretty weird. I assume you haven't messed up with the SDL_RenderSetViewport ... so post your drawSprite code.

Comment: It may actually be working correctly depending on how SDL works and how you setup your renderer.  I haven't worked with it in a looooong time but is it possible they cannot occupy the same space and your `SDL_Renderer` is trying to obey that rule?  Look into it, change some Alpha values and see what you get.

Comment: destRect.x = y; .. here is your mistake

Comment: DrawSprite added into original post.

Comment: @jnbbender I can't think of any configuration where a texture/surface would not be rendered if another was drawn partially covering it. It would simply display in order of rendering calls ie last called would be drawn on top

Comment: Oh wow, so simple. Thank you very much though guys!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are setting up the destination `SDL_Rect` incorrectly by assigning `destRect.x = y` it should be `destRect.x = x`

```
void SpriteLoader::drawSprite(std::string id, int x, int y, int width, int height, SDL_Renderer* renderer, SDL_RendererFlip flip)
{
    SDL_Rect srcRect;
    SDL_Rect destRect;

    srcRect.x = 0;
    srcRect.y = 0;
    srcRect.w = destRect.w = width;
    srcRect.h = destRect.h = height;
    destRect.x = x;   // THIS WAS THE ERROR (You had destRect.x = y;)
    destRect.y = y;

    SDL_RenderCopyEx(renderer, textures[id], &srcRect, &destRect, 0, 0, flip);
}
```